# Countdown timer not working properly in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to create a Countdown timer in the next.js
What I want to achieve is A timer that expires after let's say 4 HOURS. I have used `setInterval` function inside `useEffect`

It is affecting the component's other data they are also refreshing. refer https://www.loom.com/share/d902cf2010944f6b89462208237f195c

Here is what I have tried following

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { endPoints } from "../../../../constant/endpoints";
import { randomNo } from "../../../../utils/functions";
import Ratings from "react-ratings-declarative";


function TodaysDeal(params) {
  const rattingValue = randomNo(3, 5);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [productsImages, setProductsImages] = useState([
    "https://dummyimage.com/400x400",
  ]);
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState({
    hours: "00",
    minutes: "00",
    seconds: "00",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(countDownTimer, 1000);
    setLoading(true);
    fetchProducts();
  }, []);

  const countDownTimer = () => {
    const difference = +new Date("2022-09-10T17:37:56+00:00") - +new Date();
    let timeLeft = {};
    console.log("difference: ", difference);
    if (difference > 0) {
      timeLeft = {
        hours: Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60)),
        minutes: Math.floor((difference / 1000 / 60) % 60),
        seconds: Math.floor((difference / 1000) % 60),
      };
    }
    setTimeLeft(timeLeft);
    //return timeLeft;
  };

  const fetchProducts = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(`${endPoints.products}/${randomNo(1, 200)}`);
      const _data = await res.json();
      setProducts(_data);
      setProductsImages(_data.images);
      setLoading(false);
      console.log("deals of the day: ", _data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("try catch error logs: =====> ", err);
      setLoading(false);
      setError(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <section className="pt-20 pb-20 body-font">
      <div className="container px-5 mx-auto uppercase font-bold tracking-widest">
        <div className="flex flex-wrap">
          <div className="md:w-3/5">
            <h1 className="text-gray-800 text-8xl display-block">
              Deal of the day
            </h1>
          </div>
          <div className="md:w-2/5">
            <h1 className="text-gray-800 text-8xl display-block text-center">
              <span>{timeLeft.hours}</span>
              <span>:</span>
              <span>{timeLeft.minutes}</span>
              <span>:</span>
              <span>{timeLeft.seconds}</span>
            </h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <section className="text-gray-600 body-font overflow-hidden">
        <div className="container px-5 py-10 mx-auto">
                  .
                  .
                  .
                  .
                  .
                  .
        </div>
      </section>
    </section>
  );
}

export default TodaysDeal;
```

Please correct me. Thanks!

Comment: Nice to learn that `+new Date("time")` converts a datetime to timestamp.

Comment: My guess is that `fetchProducts` is being called more than once.

Comment: @NiceBooksYes. and i am not able to figure out why.

Comment: Please check how many times your `useEffect(,.,,[])` & `fetchProducts` are called. You can use the Network tab of your browser's devtools, to check how many times the endpoint is accessed.

Comment: I have checked the network tab. it is executing once. what I have did on rating, no of reviews, and product price(the line through). it getting randoms via the custom js function.

Answer (score 1):

reactStrictMode calls useEffect twice. So it might be making all those calls inside useEffect run twice. Try disabling it from next.config.js.

Correct way would be to check before making any async call. Preventing multiple calls. Or clear ongoing calls e.g clearInterval

Comment: it is already disabled

Answer (score 0):

It seems `fetchProducts` is being called more than once, even though inside the `TodaysDeal` component its being called only from `useEffect(..,[])` equivalent to `componentDidMount`.

Hence it can be inferred that the `TodaysDeal` is destroyed mounted multiple times.

In any case, there needs to be a `clearInterval`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    var interval = setInterval(countDownTimer, 1000);
    setLoading(true);
    fetchProducts();
    return ()=> {
        // This function is run once when the component is unmounted
        // equivalent to componentWillUnmount
        clearInterval(interval);
    };
}, []);
```

**edited:fix typo**

Comment: That's not working